# Como implementar devolução de produtos?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, aplicação-desktop

Estou tendo dificuldades em implementar um requisito na modelagem do banco de dados, este requisito corresponde a devolução de produtos.

**Este é o cenário que ocorre as devoluções e os modos diferentes de devolução de produtos:**

- *O Cliente compra apenas um produto e devolve o mesmo*;
- *O Cliente compra dois ou mais produtos e devolve apenas um deles*;
- *O Cliente compra um Kit que contem vários produtos e devolve o Kit
  inteiro*;
- *O Cliente compra um Kit que contem vários produtos e devolve alguns
  produtos deste Kit*;

Eu criei um exemplo para ilustrar a modelagem do módulo de vendas, para que vocês entendam a lógica, segue a imagem:
[image: Diagrama de Vendas]

O diagrama acima ilustra como esta meu banco de dados em relação a vendas de produto, porem não coloquei todos os campos se não ia conter muita informação dificultando o entendimento, mas a lógica é esta, também não coloquei a tabela de *Vendedor* e nem a de *Cliente*, mas, ambas as duas se relacionam com a tabela de *Vendas*.

**Será necessário registrar as seguintes informações da devolução**:

- *Os produtos desenvolvidos ou Kits*;
- *O cliente responsável pela devolução*;
- *O vendedor para quem o cliente devolveu o(s) produto(s)*;
- *A venda correspondente*;
- *Hora e Data da devolução*;

O campo *id_kit* na tabela *Item*, pode conter valores 0 (nulos), esta tabela pode representar um Item como produto da venda ou um Kit como produto.

Com as informações acima como posso fazer a modelagem da(s) tabela(s) correspondente a devolução de produtos?

Comment: Esse diagrama foi feito no brModelo ne?

Comment: Sim usei ele, para criar o diagrama.

Comment: Bem q notei que já tinha visto o tipo de diagrama em algum lugar :D

Comment: quado em uma venda acontece somente a saída de um produto o valor do campo id_kit é 0?

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que a modelagem das devoluções deve ser pensada sobre os produtos, também porque o cliente pode devolver um produto de um kit hoje e após alguns dias devolver outro produto do mesmo kit. 
Dessa forma, quando o cliente devolver um kit inteiro todos os produtos do mesmo devem ser registrados como devolvidos separadamente. Também para controle de estoque. Se o produto não possuir um kit na tabela de devoluções a coluna referente ficará nula.

Exemplo da tabela:

**Devolucoes**

`id_devolucao`
`id_item` - coluna da tabela *ITEM* que já possuíra a referencia da venda;
`id_cliente` - quem devolveu;
`id_vendedor` - o vendedor que recebeu a devolução;
`id_produto` - o produto devolvido;
`id_kit` - caso possua kit;
`dthr_devolucao`

Comment: Neste caso eu poderia usar o id_venda? Porque o id_item é apenas um identificador da tabela Item, que são os itens da venda.

Comment: poderia sim, mas se o seu sistema permitir a existência de 2 itens iguais(não quantidade = 2) você não poderá indicar qual deles foi devolvido. Se você manter o id_item, além de ter essa informação, saberá o id da venda porque a tabela ITEM o possuí